# Увеличить кнопки и расстояние между ними блок «Поделиться» Яндекс

Tags: javascript, ya-share2

Возможно-ли увеличить **размер** и **расстояние** между кнопками в блоке «Поделиться» Яндекс. 
В мобильной версии очень маленькие кнопки и расстояние (по горизонтали) маленькое не удобно нажимать, задевается ближняя кнопка.

Код:

```html
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/yandex-share2/share.js"></script>
    <div class="ya-share2" data-services="vkontakte,facebook,odnoklassniki,moimir,viber,whatsapp,skype,telegram"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CSS вам в помощь. Можете добавить медиа-запросы для кастомизации под разные размеры экранов.

```css
.ya-share2__item {
   margin-right: 24px !important;   
}

.ya-share2__icon {
   height: 48px !important;
   width: 48px !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/yandex-share2/share.js"></script>
    <div class="ya-share2" data-services="vkontakte,facebook,odnoklassniki,moimir,viber,whatsapp,skype,telegram"></div>
```

Comment: @teranБлагодарю работает.